# como Ativar "allow oem unlock' no Android via fastboot?

Tags: android-sdk

Efetuei o acesso root no meu Moto G 2ºGer XT1078 através do app Kingroot, mas quando reiniciei o aparelho cai direto na tela AP FASTBOOT FLASH MODE (S)

Tentei efetuar um reset mas apresenta varias mensagens de erro:

```
failed to validate ftm image  
that means its not fih ftm mode  
load and validate boot image  
hab check failed for boot  
failed to verify hab image boot  
failed to validate boot image
```

O agravante é que não sabia que deveria deixar selecionado a opção:

```
Configurações -> Dev Settings -> "Allow OEM Unlock"
```